# Does "Acer AS5560-8354G64MNrr" laptop supports AMD Virtualization?

Tags: bios, virtualization, acer-aspire

I'm trying for a long time, to get some information about this problem, but I never found anything... I can't find Virtualization option on my "Phoenix" BIOS. But never get any solutions about it.

Windows 10 shows me it's enabled, but Virtualbox, Genymotion, installing Ubuntu... gives me error at runtime for example...

I updated my BIOS from Acer download drivers (Acer Aspire 5560 (15")) but still not working.

My laptop uses **A8-3520M**.

Comment: Easier to provide us the specifications of the laptop, Acer is natorious for having country specific models.  So provide us the CPU your model has.  Provide us the error.

Comment: Recently updated!

Comment: That processor supports virtualization.  http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/K10/AMD-A8-Series%20A8-3520M.html

Comment: Thanks you very much, I was reading an article and I have come to the conclusion that on W10 Home cannot use Virtualization...